# Sync Center Offline Files - auto resolve conflicts and disable offline files

Tags: windows-7, sync, offline-files

I am looking for a way to resolve sync conflicts, initiate an offline files sync, then disable offline files all by command line or powershell...Windows 7

I have a ton of computers that installed an update about a year ago or so that enabled the offline files. now, I'm coming up to a migration to windows 10 and really need to resolve these conflicts before I can migrate the computers. The real trick is, on a lot of the computers I have multiple users. Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you upgrade to Win 10 now? Ignore conflicts or remove whatever's causing the problem (offline files?)

Answer (score 0):

More of a suggestion, but it's technically an answer, so:

Ignore the conflicts. Remove / uninstall whatever's causing the conflicts (offline-files?) and:

- Backup all the users & data
- Upgrade to windows 10
- Restore the users & data